# What is a "finite $\sigma$-algebra"?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have an exersice which is outlined as follows

Suppose $G_{i}$ where $i=0 \ldots n$ is a disjoint union of $\Omega$. Prove that the family of unions of these $G_{i}$ is a sigma algebra on $\Omega$. Also prove that any "finite sigma algebra" $\mathcal{F}$ on $\Omega$ is of this form.

My guess is that a finite sigma algebra is a sigma algebra with finite number of sets but I am not sure.

I cant find the definition anywhere, does anyone know where I can find it?

Comment: $\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ is an example of a finite sigma-algebra.

Comment: @GabrielRomon good example

Comment: @GabrielRomon Indeed. And $\Omega$ is allowed to be infinite here.

Comment: @drhab right, that kinda bothers me, but ill go with your suggestion for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A $\sigma$-algebra on space $\Omega$ is a subset of $\wp(\Omega)$ with special properties.

That means that a finite $\sigma$-algebra is a [finite subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_set) of $\wp(\Omega)$ with these properties.

Answer (score 2):

As you guessed, a finite $\sigma$-algebra is just a $\sigma$-algebra that is finite.

As mentioned in the comments, a $\sigma$-algebra is a set, so when we describe a $\sigma$-algebra as "finite" we are using the standard definition of a finite set.

Comment: It is wierd that one cannot find it written down anywhere. When one has infinite operations one can always get supprised.

Comment: @user1 see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_set) and realize that a $\sigma$-algebra is a set. In fact you allready did that. Your guess is fine.

Comment: @drhab Thanks ill go with that for now.

Comment: @user1 a sigma-algebra is a set, first and foremost !

Comment: @drhab u wanna write that in answer or let littleO  add it to his? I think this comment is vital.

Comment: so a finite sigma algebra it’s just an algebra, right?